# tmux error in chroot

Tags: tmux, chroot

I set up a chroot and copied `tmux` and all the required libraries. When I log in as the chroot user and run `tmux`, I get the error `tmux: invalid LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE or LANG`. How do I fix the error?

Comment: Does setting e.g. `export LC_ALL=C` in the chroot make it work?

Comment: Now it gives a different error: `tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE) but have ANSI_X3.4-1968
`.